# how to automatically classify a list of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

Well, the context is: I have a list of wind speeds, let's imagine, 100 wind measurements from 0 to 50 km/h, so I want to automate the creation of a list by uploading the csv, let's imagine, every 5 km/h, that is, the ones that they go from 0 to 5, what go from 5 to 10... etc.

Let's go to the code:

```
wind = pd.read_csv("wind.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(wind)
x = df["Value"]
d = sorted(pd.Series(x))
lst = [[] for i in range(0,(int(x.max())+1),5)]
```

this gives me a list of empty lists, i.e. if the winds go from 0 to 54 km/h will create 11 empty lists.

Now, to classify I did this:

```
for i in range(0,len(lst),1):
    for e in range(0,55,5):
       for n in d:
            if n>e and n< (e+5):
               lst[i].append(n)
            else:
                continue
```

My objective would be that when it reaches a number greater than 5, it jumps to the next level, that is, it adds 5 to the limits of the interval (e) and jumps to the next i to fill the second empty list in lst. I tried it in several ways because I imagine that the loops must go in a specific order to give a good result. This code is just an example of several that I tried, but they all gave me similar results, either all the lists were filled with all the numbers, or only the first list was filled with all the numbers

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(wind)` is totally redundant - `read_csv` already gave you a `DataFrame`. `d = sorted(pd.Series(x))` is totally redundant, `x = df["Value"]` already gave you a `Series`, but now you're using `python` methods on a `pandas`/`numpy` object

Comment: This is a misuse of `pandas`. It would be much better if you gave an example dataset so that someone can correct this logic for you

Comment: the dataset could be any list of random numbers, in this case this are measures but they seems like random number between 0 and 55, you can see that, like sort a simply list of random numbers in intervals automatically no matter the size

Comment: If you're using `pandas`, there's almost always a way to achieve your intended result without using Python `for`-loops; especially a triple-nested `for/for/for`!  It sounds like you want to bin your values into groups from 0-4.99, 5-9.99, etc., yes?

Comment: It looks likes [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) will bin the data as you desire, given an appropriate `IntervalIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title mentions *classify*ing the numbers -- are you looking for a categorical output like `calm | gentle breeze | strong breeze | moderate gale | etc.`? If so, take a look at the second example on the [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) docs.

Since you're already using `pandas`, use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with an `IntervalIndex` (constructed with the [`pd.interval_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.interval_range.html) function) to get a `Series` of bins, and then `groupby` on that.

```py
import pandas as pd
from math import ceil

BIN_WIDTH = 5

wind_velocity = (pd.read_csv("wind.csv")["Value"]).sort_values()

upper_bin_lim = BIN_WIDTH * ceil(wind_velocity.max() / BIN_WIDTH)
bins = pd.interval_range(
    start=0,
    end=upper_bin_lim,
    periods=upper_bin_lim//BIN_WIDTH,
    closed='left')
velocity_bins = pd.cut(wind_velocity, bins)
groups = wind_velocity.groupby(velocity_bins)

for name, group in groups:
    #TODO: use `groups` to do stuff
```